# How to print without newline in CMake?

Tags: cmake

It's all in the title. The [message documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/message.html) does not propose any option to do so, but is there really no way to write some text using CMake without having it silently add a newline?

The idea is to print something like "Adding library...", and later print "Done" but keeping both messages on the same line;

Comment: I feel `Adding library...` and then `Adding library... Done` as STATUS message is a natural way for CMake. At least, I used such variant of printing in my projects.

Comment: But `message( STATUS "Adding library..." )` actually outputs "Adding library...\n"...

Comment: Yes. I meant I intentionally printed **two lines**: the first at the beginning of the durable work, and the second at the end of that work.

Comment: Thing is my log is huge (with hunderds of libs), so I wanted something as short as possible, with a single line per module (I provide w verbose mode with more info available...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CMake's [command mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) to print without newline:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append "Adding library...")
...
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Done")
```